# How to add a focus ring to a menu item in html

Tags: html, label, focus, wai-aria

Is this even possible if I have a menu item such as below?

```
<li class="dropdown"><a <">data-</c:if>href="url"?
                    class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"><fmt:message
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `tabindex`:

```html
<ol>
  <li tabindex="-1">Item 1</li>
  <li tabindex="-1">Item 2</li>
  <li tabindex="-1">Item 3</li>
  <li tabindex="-1">Item 4</li>
  <li tabindex="-1">Item 5</li>
<ol>
```

Note that this isn't the most accessible way of doing things, so if what you really want is to outline an `<li>` when a link inside it has focus, you can use this CSS (try tabbing through the example below):

```css
li:focus-within {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

li a {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
<ol>
```

Comment: This is helpful but what if these 5 items were under one parent menu, and it was the parent menu I want highlighted when I tab over it

Comment: @testtest: instead of speculation, how about editing your question to show the HTML you're working with, and explaining where your current approach fails. Please: read the "*[mcve]*" guidelines, and consider taking the [tour].

Comment: @testtest You would just change `li:focus-within` to `ol:focus-within` or `ul:focus-within`.